# What is the difference between a negative linear regulator and a positive one?

Tags: voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

I am looking for a voltage regulator V<sub>in</sub> = 5 V, V<sub>out</sub> = 3.3 V, I<sub>out</sub> = 400 mA.

In my search I found negative linear regulators as well as positive ones. What is the difference and why can I find more negative ones for higher current than positive ones?

Comment: I think you mean "why *can't* you find more negative ones for higher current"

Comment: no my question really was just why are there positive and negative ones and what are they used for

Comment: You said "why can I find more negative ones for higher current than positive ones", but there are fewer negative linear regulators than positive ones.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking why you can't just use a configuration like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhMU48.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I used to wonder the same thing. The reason this doesn't work is that a positive linear voltage regulator does *not* like sinking current. If current ever goes *into* the out terminal of a voltage regulator, it will at best stop regulating and at worst completely break the regulator. As such, negative voltage regulators, which are designed to sink current at their output rather than source it, are used instead, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCLiFK.png)</sup>

(n.b.: I've left off the capacitors from these circuits just to keep them clean and to the point. Of course you would actually need input and output capacitors for each regulator.)

Comment: Wouldn't the output of your first circuit be +9 V wrt the node you labelled ground?

Comment: @VladimirCravero You are correct. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Some positive regulators can sink current, but even on those that can do so, regulation would be very poor whenever the current to/from the output switches direction.  Further, power dissipation in a linear regulator is generally proportional to the current times the difference between the input and output voltages, but when a regulator is consuming power from the output, power dissipation would be proportional to the output voltage times current.

Comment: @supercat I've never seen one that does! Do you know of any particular part numbers?

Comment: @Hearth: I think I've seen such behavior in some voltage references, which are effectively precision voltage regulators which aren't intended to output much current.  If a device is only sourcing or sinking 1mA, power dissipation isn't anywhere near as much of an issue as if it's sourcing or sinking 1A.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are also correct but it might be a bit difficult to "see" how positive and negative regulators work so here's a typical example of a "symmetric power supply" that outputs +15 V and -15 V:

[image]

The LM7815 is a **positive** voltage regulator, it takes a positive voltage (of around + 20 V) and makes a stable +15 V from that.

The LM7915 is a **negative** voltage regulator, it takes a negative voltage (of around - 20 V) and makes a stable -15 V from that.

Such a supply is often used to power circuits with opamps like audio amplifiers.

Answer (score 6):

If the positive voltage regulator is the NPN version, the negative voltage regulator is the PNP version.

Another way to think of it is the following:

If you take a positive voltage regulator, and get its transistor-level representation, then you can derive the complementary negative regulator by flipping the polarity of the whole thing -- each NPN becomes a PNP, each PNP becomes an NPN, and each diode gets flipped around.

Comment: Planned improvement -- verbage:    If a positive discrete regulator looks like this, a negative discrete regulator looks like this...(show). Put together in a bipolar supply, they would look like this, which is similar to the regulator level representations in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Many circuits require, or perform better with, two polarities of power supplies.  Analog circuits for audio and video are common examples.

There are far more positive regulator ICs and modules than negative on the market.  This is because there are relatively few circuit topologies that require only a negative voltage source for power.  Fun fact: landline phone systems run on -48 V.

Answer (score 0):

There are complementary ICs so you are able to add eg +5V and -5V regulators to create a 10V supply. When there is only the need of one voltage voltage you should use the positive one.